# Installing SVGAnnotation package under R 2.15.3

Tags: r, svg

I have troubles installing the SVGAnnotation package under R 2.15.3

Because this package is not available at CRAN, I downloaded version 0.93-1 from http://www.omegahat.org/SVGAnnotation/

and try to install it via

```
install.packages("SVGAnnotation_0.93-1.tar.gz", repos=NULL, 
type="source")
```

Unfortunately, the following problem occurs:

[image]

Anyone has an idea how I could get it to work for R 2.15.3?

Comment: Have you tried installing it directly from Bioconductor? In particular, it serves up binary packages, which would make installation easier.

    source("http://bioconductor.org/biocLite.R"); 
    biocLite("SVGAnnotation")

Comment: Thanks, this worked! However, it would be great to install the most recent version somehow in future.

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to install the most recent version, try

`library(devtools)`

`install_github('duncantl/SVGAnnotation')`